# html table padding/margin not working on the next page

Tags: html, css, html-table, dompdf

i have an dompdf report that use html table that is set to have the margin/padding top to 275px, to follow up with my fixed-header. But the table's margin/padding top doesn't work on the next page of the report. here's my code:

```
This is my fixed header code:
.fixed-header{
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        padding-top: 80px;
        position: fixed;
}
.fixed-header{
        top: 0;
}

And this is my table's code:
.my-table {
        padding-top: 275px;
        margin-bottom: 25px; 
        font-size: 10pt;
}
```

This is the first page (what i want it looks like)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjMi2.png

And this the second page (where the padding-top not working):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD2HF.png

My complete code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<?php 
use App\Models\Joborder; 
use App\Models\Kapal;
use App\Models\InvoicearpbmDetail;
?>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    
    <title>NOTA TAGIHAN / INVOICE</title>
    <style>
        @page {
            border: solid 1px #0b93d5;
            width: 24.13cm;
            height: 27.94cm;
            font-family: 'Courier';
            font-weight: bold;
            margin-right: 1cm;
        }

        .title {
            margin-top: 1.2cm;
        }
        .title h1 {
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 14pt;
            
        }
        }

        .header {
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            /*font-size: 10pt;*/
            padding-top: 0px;
            /*border: solid 1px #0b93d5;*/
        }

        .left {
            float: left;
        }

        .right {
            float: right;
        }

        .clearfix {
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .content {
            padding-top: 75px
        }
        .catatan {
            font-size: 10pt;
        }

        /* Table desain*/
        table.grid {
            width: 100%;
        }
        table.grid th{
            background: #FFF;
            text-align:left;
            /*padding-left:0.2cm;*/
            /*padding-right:0.2cm;*/
            /*border:1px solid #fff;*/
            padding-bottom:3mm;
        }

        table.grid tr td{
            /*padding-top:0.5mm;*/
            /*padding-bottom:0.5mm;*/
            padding-left:2mm;
            padding-right:2mm;
            /*border:1px solid #fff;*/
        }
        .list-item {
            height: 2.1in;
            margin: 0px;
        }

        .gfg { 
            border-collapse:separate; 
            border-spacing:0 10px; 
        } 

        .my-table {
            padding-top: 275px;
            margin-bottom: 25px; 
            font-size: 10pt;
        }
        
        .fixed-header{
            margin-left: 0px;
            margin-right: 0px;
            /*font-size: 10pt;*/
            padding-top: 80px;
            position: fixed;
            /*border: solid 1px #0b93d5;*/
        }
        .fixed-header{
            top: 0;
        }
        
        #header .page:after {
          content: counter(page, decimal);
        }
        
        .page_break { page-break-after: always; }
    </style>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="fixed-header">
        <div class="title">
            <h1>NOTA TAGIHAN / INVOICE</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="left">
            <table width="50%" style="  font-size: 10pt" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 65px">Kepada</td>
                    <td>{{ $customer->nama_customer_po }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Alamat</td>
                    <td>{{ $customer->alamat }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{ $customer->alamat2 }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td>{{ $customer->kota }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td >NPWP</td>
                    <td>{{ $customer->npwp }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="right">
            <table width="50%" style="padding-left:8em; font-size: 9pt" border="0">
                <tr>
                    <td style="width: 115px">No Invoice</td>
                    <td>{{ $invoicear->no_invoice }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Tgl Invoice</td>
                    <td>{{ $invoicear->tgl_invoice }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No. Job Order</td>
                    <td>{{ $invoicear->no_jo }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>No. Reff</td>
                    <td>{{ $invoicear->no_bl }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Kapal</td>
                    <?php
                        $namakapal = "-";
                        if (Auth()->user()->kode_company == '02'){
                            $job = Joborder::on('mysql_front_pbm')->where('no_joborder', $invoicear->no_jo)->first();
                            if($job->kode_kapal != null)
                            {
                                $kapal = Kapal::on('mysql7')->where('kode_kapal', $job->kode_kapal)->first();
                                $namakapal = $kapal->nama_kapal;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $kapal = "-";
                            }
                        }else if(Auth()->user()->kode_company == '06') {
                            $job = Joborder::on('mysql_front_inf')->where('no_joborder', $invoicear->no_jo)->first();
                            if($job->kode_kapal != null)
                            {
                                $kapal = Kapal::on('mysql10')->where('kode_kapal', $job->kode_kapal)->first();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                $kapal = "-";
                            }
                        }
                    ?>
                    
                    <td>{{ $namakapal }}</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Lokasi</td>
                    <td>{{ $job->lokasi }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
        
    <table class="my-table" width="100%" border="0">
        <thead>
            <tr><td colspan="4"><hr></td></tr>
            <tr >
                <td style="width: 380px;">Description</td>
                <td style="width: 80px; text-align: right;">Qty</td>
                <td style="width: 105px; text-align: right;">Unit Rate</td>
                <td style="width: 125px; text-align: right;">Total</td>
            </tr>
            <tr><td colspan="4"><hr></td></tr>
        </thead>
        <?php
            $mobdemob = 0;
            $no = 0;
        ?>
        <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($invoiceardetail as $key => $value): ?>
            <?php $no += 1; ?>
            <tr >
                <td style="width: 380px; word-spacing: -4px;"><?php echo $value->keterangan ?></td>
                <td style="width: 80px; text-align: right;"><?php echo number_format($value->qty,'3') ?></td>
                <td style="width: 105px; text-align: right;"><?php echo number_format($value->harga_satuan,'2') ?></td>
                <td style="width: 125px; text-align: right;"><?php echo number_format(floor($value->sub_total),'0','.',',') ?></td>
            </tr>
            <?php $mobdemob += $value->mob_demob; ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
        <?php
            $grand_total = $invoicear->grand_total;
        ?>
            <tr><td colspan="4">
            <div class="footer" style="padding-top: 0px">
                    <br>
                    <hr>
                    <div class="left">
                        <table style="padding-left:1mm; font-size:10pt; width: 55%" border="2px">
                            <td>Terbilang : <?php echo Terbilang::make(floor($after_ppn), ' rupiah'); ?></td>
                        </table>
                        
                        <table style="font-size:10pt; width: 60%" border="0px">
                            <td style="font-size: 10px; font-family: 'Arial'">All cheques must be crossed and made out in favour of <?=$nama_company?> Please notify us in writing immediately should there be any discrepancies relating to the above.</td>
                        </table>

                        <!--<p style="font-size: 10px; font-family: 'Arial'">All cheques must be crossed and made out in favour of <?=$nama_company?><br>-->
                        <!--    Please notify us in writing immediately should there be any disrepancies relating to the above.<br><br>-->

                        <p style="font-size: 12px; font-family: 'Arial'">Please arrange to transfer the balance to our account this below :<br></p>
                        <?php if(auth()->user()->kode_company == '02') { ?> 
                        <b>
                        <p style="font-size: 10pt">
                        BANK BANK BANK<br>
                        BANK BANK BANK<br>
                        A/C NO. 113.111.1111111<br>
                        BENEFICIARY : PT. BANK BANK BANK
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        BANK BANK BANK<br>
                        BANK BANK BANK<br>
                        A/C NO. 113.111.1111111<br>
                        BENEFICIARY : PT. BANK BANK BANK
                        <br>
                        <br>
                        BANK BANK BANK<br>
                        BANK BANK BANK<br>
                        A/C NO. 113.111.1111111<br>
                        BENEFICIARY : PT. BANK BANK BANK
                        </p>
                        </b>
                        <?php }else { ?>
                        <b>
                        <p style="font-size: 10pt">
                        BANK BANK BANK<br>
                        BANK BANK BANK<br>
                        A/C NO. 113.111.1111111<br>
                        BENEFICIARY : PT. BANK BANK BANK<br>
                        </p>
                        </b>
                        <?php } ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="right">
                        <table style="padding-left:20mm; font-size:10pt; text-align: right">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total Invoice</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format(floor($invoicear->total_invoice),'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php if ($mobdemob > 0) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Mob Demob</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format($mobdemob,'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php
                            if ($invoicear->disc_persen != 0) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Disc (<?php echo $invoicear->disc_persen ?>%)</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format(floor($tot_disc),'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php }
                            else if($invoicear->disc_rp != 0) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Disc</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format($tot_disc,'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } else{ ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>Disc</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0</td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Uang Muka</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format(floor($invoicear->total_um),'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- <tr>
                                <td>Sub Total</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format($after_disc - $job->mob_demob,'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                            </tr> -->
                            <tr>
                                <td>Subtotal Invoice</td>
                                <?php $disc = $invoicear->total_invoice * ($invoicear->disc_persen/100); ?>
                                <?php $subtotal = $invoicear->total_invoice - ($disc) - ($invoicear->disc_rp) - $invoicear->total_um; ?>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format(floor($after_disc),'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                            </tr>
                            <?php
                            if ($invoicear->ppn_persen != 0) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>PPN (<?php echo $invoicear->ppn_persen ?>%)</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format(floor($tot_ppn),'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php }
                            else if($invoicear->ppn_rp != 0) { ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>PPN</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format($tot_ppn,'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } else{ ?>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>PPN</td>
                                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;0</td>
                                </tr>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Grand Total</td>
                                <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?php echo number_format(floor($after_ppn),'0','.',',') ;?></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <br><br>
                        <div class="tgl" style="font-size: 10pt">
                            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Palembang, <?php echo date_format($date,'d/m/Y');?>
                        </div>
                        <br><br><br><br><br>
                        <p style="font-size: 10pt">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<?=$nama_company?></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td></tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

is there any solution to this?

Comment: What do you mean by next page? Can you provide code or a link so that we can re-produce the problem?

Comment: i mean on the second page when the table's data is more than one page to contain.

Comment: provide HTML code, so i can help u easily

Comment: @Armankazi there, i have add my complete code

Comment: Set the margin in the `@page` and correct any CSS errors (namely the double `} }`)

Comment: @agrm thanks for the advice, i've add it to the page and add the reversal to the fixed-header section and it works fine !!